# Slutsky's theorem applied to a sample mean conditional on a Bernoulli variable?

Tags: mean, convergence, asymptotics, slutsky-theorem

Let $(Z_{i},Y_{2i})$, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$ be iid random vectors, where $Y_{2i}$ is the outcome vector and $Z_{i}\sim\operatorname{Bernoulli}(\delta)$. Assume that
$E(Y_{2i}|Z_{i})=\mu_{2}+\beta Z_{i}$ and $Var(Y_{2i}|Z_{i})=\sigma_{22}^{(1)}Z_{i} + \sigma_{22}^{(0)}(1-Z_{i})$.

Let $\bar{Y_{2}}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}Y_{2i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}$ be the standard sample mean estimator for $\mu_{2}+\beta$. It is easy to see that
$\bar{Y_{2}} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \frac{E(Z_{i}Y_{2i})}{E(Z_{i})}=\mu_{2}+\beta$. Also,
$E(\bar{Y_{2}}|\boldsymbol{Z})=(\mu_{2}+\beta)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}$ and
$Var(\bar{Y_{2}}|\boldsymbol{Z})=\sigma_{22}^{(1)}/\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}$. By the law of total variance,

$$
Var(\bar{Y_{2}})=
N^{-1}\sigma_{22}^{(1)}E\left(\frac{1}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}\right)
+Var\left\{
(\mu_{2}+\beta)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}
\right\}.
$$
I suppose that these expectations do not exist in finite samples as $\Pr\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}=0\right)>0$, but as $N\rightarrow \infty$, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}/\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}=1$ a.s., hence $Var\left\{
(\mu_{2}+\beta)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}
\right\}\approx 0$ for sufficiently large $N$. Also, as $N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}\overset{p}{\longrightarrow} \delta$,  $E\left(\frac{1}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}\right)\approx1/\delta$ for $N\rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, the asymptotic variance of $\bar{Y_{2}}$ appears to be

$$
Var(\bar{Y_{2}}) \approx \frac{\sigma_{22}^{(1)}}{N\delta}
\Rightarrow Var(\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{2}}) \approx \frac{\sigma_{22}^{(1)}}{\delta}
$$

**Applying Slutsky's theorem**

However, $\bar{Y_{2}}$ can be alternatively expressed as
$\bar{Y_{2}}=\frac{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}Y_{2i}}{\delta}\frac{\delta}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}$. Let
$\bar{Y_{N}}=\frac{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}Y_{2i}}{\delta}$, thus,
$\bar{Y_{2}}=\bar{Y_{N}}\frac{\delta}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}$. Since $\frac{\delta}{N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}Z_{i}}\overset{p}{\longrightarrow}1$, by Slutsky's theorem, $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{2}}$ and $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{N}}$ should have the same limiting distribution.

As $Var(Z_{i}Y_{2i})=\sigma_{22}^{(1)}\delta + (\mu_{2}+\beta)^{2}\delta(1-\delta)$ (using e.g. the total variance formula), it can be shown that

$$Var(\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{N}})=\frac{\sigma_{22}^{(1)}}{\delta} + \frac{(\mu_{2}+\beta)^{2}(1-\delta)}{\delta}$$
Thus, it seems that the variances of $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{2}}$ and $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{N}}$ differ by $(\mu_{2}+\beta)^{2}(1-\delta)/\delta$, though  according to Slutsky's theorem, $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{2}}$ and $\sqrt{N}\bar{Y_{N}}$ should converge to the same limiting distribution as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

Obviously, something must be incorrect but I haven't figured it out yet.